# Calculus - Increasing function Problem

Tags: calculus, functions

Find all values for $a\in \mathbb R$ so the function  $\, f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + 3x - 1\,$ is always increasing in $\mathbb R$:

$\ f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + 3 $ , So for the function to be increasing, $\,f'(x) $ must be greater than $ 0.$

Therefore $ a\gt -3(x^2+1)/2x $

Is this right for an answer ? Thank you.

Comment: think about the negative  discriminant

Comment: You want to find the value of $a$ for which the graph of the parabola $y=3x^2+2ax+3$ is above the $x$-axis.

Comment: You solve $f'(x) \ge 0 \text{ for } a \text{ instead of } x$ where you assumed $x>0$ since you didn't change the direction of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

In order for $y^\prime=3x^2+2ax+3$ to be positive for any $x$ the graph cannot intersect the $x$-axis which means that the discriminant

$$ b^2-4ac=4a^2-36$$

must be negative. Therefore

$$ -3<a<3$$

Answer (score 0):

You should think about whether dividing by x was actually allowed. Remember that x could be 0, since you need that inequality to hold for all real x. For $3x^2+2ax+3$ to be above the x axis, it cannot have any real roots. So it must have this quantity $b^2-4ac$ (the discriminant) be negative. You know what b and c are and you can solve for a.